# how to create a model in javascript to make sure all properties does exists

Tags: javascript, model, redux, normalize

i wonder how to create models in javascript ?

example Object user: should have these properties `[name,username,password]`, and no other properties should be there.

now i want to send in any value it should return an objects with these 3 properties and ignore any other props.

i tried using

```
var UserFactory = props => ({
  user    :props.user||'',
  username:props.username||'',
  ..etc
})
```

now when ever i pass user object arround im sure all properties does exists and no undefined error may occur.

reason i want this is to normalize data when fetching/posting to server.

is there an already best practice to how to do this ?

p.s: if it matters, i'm using this in a react-redux learning project ..

thanks

**Edit
problem with code above:**

1. i cannot do type check because what factory returns is a plain object not instance of a model `userFactory({}) instanceOf UserObject === false` so how to make sure if a variable is holding a userObject inside ?
2. its verbose, yet if i use Object.assign(), i might get unwanted properties in my object, so i'm not sure if this is best way to do it.

Comment: What is wrong with what code you posted?

Comment: what problems are you actually encountering currently...provide examples

Comment: @charlietfl provided an example, please check edit

Comment: doesn't explain where extra properties come into play

Comment: @charlietfl `userFactory({badProperty:'i dont need you',fullname:'i want this',username:'and this'})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there an already best practice to how to do this ?

Yes, and this is what you are doing - using object factories. It is a common approach in JS world when constructing new models. However, instead of using ES5 approach use ES6 approach of parameter handling:

```
let UserFactory = ({user='', username='', etc...}) => { ... }
```

See more [here](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_core-features.html#sec_named-params-core-feature).

Comment: thanks, and how can i insure that variable holds an instance of a user ?

Comment: @Zalaboza, we usually don't do that in `JS`. There is `instanceOf` operator that can check whether an object has certain prototype in its prototype chain, but that's not exactly what you're looking for.  You're rarely if even need to check if object is of certain type, what you maybe concerned about is whether it has certain methods/properties - it's called [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). Consider accepting my answer if it helped